# slack responsive carousel with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, slack

I'm using slack responsive carousel to show items this items comes from array $ctrl.items and I'm using ng-repeat inside this slack carousel till now It works fine
the problem is when I click on a any button which changes the items inside $ctrl.items array 
slack starts to view the items vertically and if i changed the screen width to smaller or larger screen  the problem disappears and the slider works fine again

```
<slick
  dots="true"
  infinite="false"
  speed="300"
  slides-to-show="3"
  slides-to-scroll="3"
  responsive="[{
  breakpoint: 1024,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 600,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
}]"
>
    <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <h6>category</h6>
        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide11" />
        <h6>
          {{item.price}} €
          <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down gray"></i>
        </h6>
      </div>
    </div>

</slick>
```

Comment: Its like items added without the slack styles  then when I change the screen width the slack add the styles

Answer (score 0):

this solved the problem
For change slide content, you have to set ng-if to destroy and init it

controller:

```
    $scope.number = [{label: 1}, {label: 2}, {label: 3}, {label: 4}, {label: 5}, {label: 6}, {label: 7}, {label: 8}];
$scope.numberLoaded = true;
$scope.numberUpdate = function(){
    $scope.numberLoaded = false; // disable slick

    //number update

    $scope.numberLoaded = true; // enable slick
};
```